# Purpose of 'if __name__ == "__main__":'

Tags: python, program-entry-point

I am trying to understand some code I found which reads command line arguments (attached below). My concern is what purpose of the `"if __name__ == __main__"`line is...

Why would I use that line instead of just using the code below, `main(sys.argv[1:])`. What extra use does it provide?

```
import sys, getopt

def main(argv):
   inputfile = ''
   outputfile = ''
   try:
      opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:o:",["ifile=","ofile="])
   except getopt.GetoptError:
      print 'test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>'
      sys.exit(2)
   for opt, arg in opts:
      if opt == '-h':
         print 'test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>'
         sys.exit()
      elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
         inputfile = arg
      elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
         outputfile = arg
   print 'Input file is "', inputfile
   print 'Output file is "', outputfile

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: The canonical question is *[What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/)* (56 answers. 7,000 upvotes. 5 years prior.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well, imagine that someone else wants to use the functions in your module in their own program. They import your module... and it starts doing its own thing!

With the `if __name__ == "__main__"`, this doesn't happen. Your module only "does its thing" if it's run as the *main* module. Otherwise it behaves like a library. It encourages code reuse by making it easier.

(As [Sheng mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000075/purpose-of-if-name-main/23000094#23000094), you may want to import the module into another script yourself for testing purposes.)

Comment: this can complement https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

It is for unit test proposes.

If you are running this script directly, it will execute the `if` block. So you could do some unit test work here. But if you are importing this file as a module, you do not want this part to execute.

It is similar to the main function in Java. In every Java class, you could have a main function for unit test. But the class is imported/used as a module, the main function would not be executed.

Generally, if you're using this script directly, it will run the `if` block. Otherwise, someone would like to use this file as a library of function/class, and the test case **name** makes sure this code would not bother users.

Answer (score 5):

The `if __name__ == '__main__'` convention in Python is intended to allow you to write code that can be run directly, or imported.

If you import it, that `if` block is not executed. If you run `python.exe myscript.py` it is.

Comment: @Franz Kurt: Why not?

Answer (score 2):

This is the idiomatic way to tell whether the Python module was executed as a script, or imported from another module.  You will only enter the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block if the file was executed as a script (aka, it is the main module).