# The construct " if __name__ == '__main__' " in Python

Tags: python

I have gone through so many articles regarding this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__'
```

But I didn't get it... I am going to share you code.  What is a more brief explanation?

I have created one file, "ab.py":

```
def a():
    print('A function in ab file');

a()
```

The second file is "xy.py"

```
import ab

def b():
    print('b function')

def x():
    print ('s');

x()

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    b()
```

When I execute this code then this output is coming:

```
A function in ab file
s
b function
```

What does this mean? What is this code actually doing? Why do we implement this? Our code is also working without it.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    b()
```

Comment: I did get it from here :( I have already read this

Comment: it's like the `main(String[] args)` in Java or C#

Comment: The canonical question is *[What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/)* (56 answers. 7,000 upvotes. 6 years prior.)

Comment: Like multiple others said in the comments, this is *clearly* a duplicate.

Answer (score 38):

**You should get in the habit of using this almost always.**

Anything that comes after `if __name__ == '__main__':` will be run only when you explicitly run your file.

```
python myfile.py
```

However, if you import `myfile.py` elsewhere:

```
import myfile
```

Nothing under `if __name__ == '__main__':` will be called.

Comment: That's great explanation!

Comment: Really great explanation. @Adam

Comment: such a simple and elegant explanation!! read pages worth on this and left me more confused than before. This helps!

Comment: Simple, succinct and the exact explanation that what I was looking, thank you Adam.

Answer (score 29):

A really simple example to understand this statement is the following:

Assume that we have the following Python script named: *using_name.py*:

---

```
# Filename: using_name.py

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'This program is being run by itself'
else:
    print 'I am being imported from another module'
```

---

Now, try to do the following two things and see what happens:

---

**1) Run directly the script**

```
python using_name.py
```

**Result**

```
This program is being run by itself
```

---

**2) Import the script**

```
python

import using_name
```

**Result**

```
I am being imported from another module
```

Comment: This is _by far_ the best answer to this question.

Answer (score 4):

> What is this code actually doing?

When you execute *xy.py*, you import *ab*. The import statement runs the module on import, so *ab*'s operations get executed before the remainder of *xy*'s. Once finished with ab, it continues with *xy*.

The interpreter keeps track of which scripts are running with `__name__`. When you run a script - no matter what you've named it - the interpreter calls it `"__main__"`. That's how it keeps track of which script is the master file, the script that gets returned to after an external call to another script. (The 'home' script, you might say.)

Any other script that's called from this 'main' script is assigned its filename as its `__name__`. Hence, the line `if __name__ == "__main__" :` is the interpreter's test to determine if it's running on the script it's looking at (parsing), or if it's temporarily peeking into another script. This gives the programmer flexibility to have the script behave differently if it's called externally.

To understand what's happening, focus first on the unindented lines and the order they appear in the scripts. Remember that function - or `def` - blocks don't do anything by themselves until they're called. What the interpreter might think if mumbled to itself:

- Open *xy.py*.
- Import and open file with the `__name__` *ab.py*.
- Oh, a function. I'll remember that.
- Ok, function a(); I just learned that. I guess I'll print now.
- End of file; back to `'__main__'`!
- Oh, a function. I'll remember that.
- Another one.
- Function x(); ok, printing 's'.
- What's this? An `if` statement. Well, the condition has been met (the variable `__name__` has been set to `'__main__'`), so I'll print 'b function'.

However, I don't think you're using it properly. There are probably exceptions, but the bottom two lines should be:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

... which means "If this is the 'main' or home script, execute the function called `main()`. That's why you'll see a `def main():` block up top, which contains the main flow of the script's functionality.

> Why do we implement this?

Remember what I said earlier about import statements? When you import a module it doesn't just 'recognize' it and wait for further instructions. It actually runs all the executable operations contained within the script. So, putting the meat of your script into the `main()` function effectively quarantines it, putting it in isolation, so that it can't immediately run when imported by another script.

Again, there will be exceptions, but common practice is that `main()` doesn't usually get called externally. So you may be wondering one more thing: if we're not calling `main()`, why are we calling the script at all? It's because many people structure their scripts with stand-alone functions that are built to be run by themselves. They're then later called somewhere else in the body of the script. Which brings me to this:

> Our code is work without it also

Yes, you're right. These separate functions **can** be called from an in-line script that's not contained inside a `main()` function. If you're accustomed (as I am, in my early learning stages of programming) to building in-line scripts that do exactly what you need, and you'll try to figure it out again if you ever need that operation again - well, you're not used to this kind of internal structure to your code, because it's more complicated to build, and it's not as intuitive to read.

But that's a script that probably can't have its functions called externally, because if it did it would start calculating and assigning variables. And chances are if you're trying to reuse a function, your new script is related closely enough to the old one that there could be conflicting variables.

I should say as an aside, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000075/purpose-of-if-name-main) contains [an answer by kindall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000075/purpose-of-if-name-main/23000098#23000098) that finally helped me to understand - the *why*, not the *how*. Unfortunately it's been marked as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do), which I think is a mistake. (I'm new to this site so can't flag it yet; if you agree with me, please flag it for further mod attention.)

Comment: That doesn't seem to be valid Python code (indentation) - (?)

Comment: OK, the OP seems to have left the building (*"Last seen more than 1 year ago "*).

Answer (score 0):

In simple words everything inside `if __name__ == "__main__":` is only run when the module is execute directly by the Python interpreter (for example, `python module.py`) *or* if functions are called explicitly after importing.

### Example:

#### File *testFile.py*

```
# This will always be executed even if this module is simply imported by other file or this module is the entry point
print "I will always run in any situation. Even when this module is 'just' imported"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # This will be executed only when this module is the entry point eg. python testFile.py but not if this file is imported
    print "I will only run if this module (testFile.py) is executed directly by the Python interpreter"
```

#### File *app.py*

```
import testFile
```

---

#### Run it

```
python testFile.py
```

#### Output

```
I will always run in any situation. Even when this module is 'just' imported.

I will only run if this module (file *testFile.py*) is executed directly by the Python interpreter.
```

---

#### Run it

```
python app.py
```

#### Output

```
I will always run in any situation. Even when this module is 'just' imported
```

---

If you want to learn about the internals of `__name__` variable:
Check *[What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)*