# Error when using a csv file with URLs in scrapy python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have multiple URLs to scrape stored in a csv file where each row is a separate URL and I'm using this code to run it

```
     def start\\_requests(self): 

             with open('csvfile', 'rb') as f: 

                      list=[] 

                      for line in f.readlines(): 

                             array = line.split(',')

                             url = array[9] 

                             list.append(url) 

                    list.pop(0)
             for url in list:
                    if url != "": 

                          yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
```

It gives me the following error `IndexError: list index out of range`, can anyone help me correct this or suggest another way to use that csv file?

edit:
csv file looks like this:

```
http://example.org/page1
http://example.org/page2
```

there are 9 such rows

Comment: Would it be possible to share some of your csv file to help find what the issue is.
`IndexError: list index out of range` most likely suggests that the cause may be due to `url = array[9]`

Comment: It is literally a csv file where each row is an URL, no extra signs, no separators, nothing, and there are 9 rows for test purposes

Comment: Edited the question to show the csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by reading the csv file into a list variable without having to do some of the code above. Therefore no need to `split`, `pop` and `append`

Working example

```
import csv
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        with open('websites.csv') as csv_file:
            data = csv.reader(csv_file)
            for row in data:
                # Supposing that the data is in the first column
                url = row[0]
                if url != "":
                    # We need to check this has the http prefix or we get a Missing scheme error
                    if not url.startswith('http://') and not url.startswith('https://'):
                        url = 'https://' + url
                    yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        # Do my data extraction
        print("test")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36',
    })
    c.crawl(QuotesSpider)
    c.start()
```

Comment: It almost works perfectly, since all the urls start with https it turned them into https:// http// example .com/site1 (without spaces), but after getting rid of part of the prefix check it works fine, thank you

Comment: You are correct, my prefix check should be an `and`. I'll update it now. Anyway, glad it worked

Comment: If it's not inconvenient to you would you mind explaining or point me towards a source with an explanation why last part is necessary? if __name__ part

Comment: That part is just used to run a spider as a single python script and not via the `scrapy crawl` command. It is mentioned in the docs: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script. the `if __name__ == "__main__"` part is general python. You can find an explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28336627/if-name-main-python